# HTML Video to image IFrame

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe

I am working on a WordPress website, trying to add an iframe showing a video and then an image, but the image doesn't appear
Here's my code

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:0px;position:relative;padding-bottom:74.841%;">
  <iframe src="https://streamable.com/e/hzwvry?autoplay=1&nocontrols=1&loop=0" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen allow="autoplay" name="Video" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden;">
  </iframe>
</div>
    
<div style="width:100%;height:0px;position:relative;padding-bottom:74.841%;">
  <iframe src="https://postimg.cc/ctgJQsGf" name="Foto">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:0px;position:relative;padding-bottom:74.841%;"><iframe src="https://postimg.cc/ctgJQsGf"> name="Foto"

</iframe></div>
```

you have set the height of the div to '0px'. Change it to some other value (preferably 'auto').

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it still ends with the video's "play"button and not with a still image

Comment: @penfinoBrand can u explain what you need the code to do? Do you mean that you want an image which shows the current frame of the video? I might have misread your question.

Comment: Basically I need to show a video and after it ends, i want to show an image in the same iframe

Comment: Well, if that is the case, you could probably try to setup an event listener to listen when the video ends, and when it does, you can try changing the `src` of the iframe.